# How to integrate this function?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

How can I perform the following integral?

```
\[Xi][k_] := 1/(\[Pi] \[Sigma]^2)^(1/4) Exp[-(k^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))];
s[k_] := Sqrt[(2 \[CapitalGamma])/vg]/(k - \[CapitalDelta] + I (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Gamma])/vg);

Integrate[\[Xi][p] \[Xi][k + kp - p] (s[p] + s[k + kp - p]), {p, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

Running the integral separately returns the input. I would like to make a contour plot with varying $\Delta$ and $\sigma$

Comment: Other parameters can there be any?

Comment: What constraints are known about the parameters/variables? Are any real, positive, nonnegative,...?

Comment: Likely no chance: even Integrate[(\[Xi][p]*\[Xi][
     k + kp - p] (s[p] + s[k + kp - p])) /. {\[Sigma] -> 1, kp -> 1, 
   vg -> 1, \[CapitalDelta] -> 1, \[CapitalGamma] -> 1, \[Gamma] -> 1,
    k -> 1}, {p, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] fails.

Comment: It is necessary to break into two integrals `Integrate[E^(-p^2/\[Sigma]^2)/(
 p0 - p + I*a), {p, -Infinity, Infinity}]`

Comment: All of the parameters, besides `s` and `\[Xi]`, are real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the exact expression of the integral `Integrate[\[Xi][p] \[Xi][k + kp - p] (s[p] + s[k + kp - p]), {p, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]`. The solution method is simple but tedious. By replacing `p -> p1 + (kp + k)/2` the integral is reduced to two others, which are calculated

```
I1 = Sqrt[2] Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]/vg]
   Integrate[
   Exp[-p1^2/\[Sigma]^2]/(b1 + I*a + p1), {p1, -Infinity, Infinity}]


I2 = Sqrt[2] Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]/vg]
   Integrate[
   Exp[-p1^2/\[Sigma]^2]/(b2 + I*a - p1), {p1, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I will give the final expression

```
F[ \[CapitalGamma]_, vg_, k_, 
  kp_, \[CapitalDelta]_, \[Gamma]_, \[Sigma]_] := 
 With[{a = (\[Gamma] + \[CapitalGamma])/vg, 
   b1 = (k + kp)/2 - \[CapitalDelta], 
   b2 = k + 1/2 (-k - kp) + kp - \[CapitalDelta], 
   A = 2*I*(\[Gamma] + \[CapitalGamma])/vg - 2*\[CapitalDelta] + k + 
     kp, B = Exp[-(k + kp)^2/4/\[Sigma]^2]}, 
  Sqrt[2*\[CapitalGamma]/(Pi*\[Sigma]^2*vg)]/A*
   B*(Sqrt[2] E^((a - I b1)^2/\[Sigma]^2) Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]/
      vg] (I \[Pi] Erf[(a - I b1)/\[Sigma]] - Log[-(1/(I a + b1))] + 
        Log[1/(I a + b1)]) + 
     Sqrt[2] E^((a - I b2)^2/\[Sigma]^2) Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]/
      vg] (I \[Pi] Erf[(a - I b2)/\[Sigma]] - Log[-(1/(I a + b2))] + 
        Log[1/(I a + b2)]))]
```

Use the function `F[]` to build

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Re[F[1, 1, 1, 1, x, 1, y]]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, .5, 5}, 
 Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  FrameLabel -> {"\[CapitalDelta]", "\[Sigma]"}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: fig1]

Let's check that `F[]` really describes the desired integral. Calculate

```
\[Xi] = 1/(\[Pi] \[Sigma]^2)^(1/4) Exp[-(k^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))];
s = Sqrt[(2 \[CapitalGamma])/vg]/(k - \[CapitalDelta] + 
     I (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Gamma])/vg);
f1 = \[Xi] /. k -> p;
f2 = \[Xi] /. k -> k + kp - p;
g1 = s /. k -> p;
g2 = s /. k -> k + kp - p;
f = FullSimplify[f1*f2*g1*g2]
 NIntegrate[
 f /. {\[CapitalGamma] -> 1, vg -> 1, k -> 1, 
   kp -> 1, \[CapitalDelta] -> 1, \[Gamma] -> 1, \[Sigma] -> 
    2}, {p, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*Out[]= -0.295116 - 1.02117*10^-18 I*)
```

and compare with

```
F[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.]

(*Out[]= -0.295116 + 0. I*)
```

To determine `A,B,a,b1,b2`, consider the identities

```
A = 2*I*(\[Gamma] + \[CapitalGamma])/vg - 2*\[CapitalDelta] + k + kp;
B = Exp[-(k + kp)^2/4/\[Sigma]^2];
g1*g2 - Sqrt[2*\[CapitalGamma]/vg]/A*(g1 + g2) // FullSimplify
(*Out[]= 0*)

(k + kp - p)^2 + p^2 /. p -> p1 + (kp + k)/2 // 
  Expand // Simplify

(*Out[]= 1/2 (k^2 + 2 k kp + kp^2 + 4 p1^2)*)


g11 = g1 /. p -> p1 + (kp + k)/2

(*Out[]= (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]/vg])/((k + kp)/2 + p1 + (
 I (\[Gamma] + \[CapitalGamma]))/vg - \[CapitalDelta])*)

g22 = g2 /. p -> p1 + (kp + k)/2

(*Out[]= (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]/vg])/(k + 
 1/2 (-k - kp) + kp - p1 + (
 I (\[Gamma] + \[CapitalGamma]))/vg - \[CapitalDelta])*)
```

Then integrals `I1` and `I2` are defined using `g11,g22`.
Level lines of the function `Abs[F[]]` for a pair `k, kp` and `\[CapitalGamma], vg`

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Abs[F[1, 1, k, kp, 1, 1, 1]]], {k, -5, 5}, {kp, -5, 5}, 
 Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  FrameLabel -> {"k", "kp"}, PlotPoints -> 50]

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Abs[F[x, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]], {x, .0, 2}, {y, .1, 2}, 
 Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  FrameLabel -> {"\[CapitalGamma]", "vg"}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: How come you defined the parameters `a`, `b1`,`b2`,`A`, and `B`? i.e. is there any  speedup?

Comment: @Sid See update to my answer.

Comment: As you see, plotting the function without the `Re[]` fails to compute. Instead of using `Re[]`, how could I plot the integral over `k` and `kp` of the absolute value of `F[]`. I have tried splitting the integrals apart but its doesn't seem to work. I may ask this as a separate question.

Comment: @Sid See update to my answer.

Comment: Some confusion stemming from my inaccurate explanation in the last comment. I meant something like this: `ContourPlot[Integrate[F[] Conjugate[F[]], {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]},{kp, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], {\[CapitalDelta], -5,5}, {\[Sigma], 0.5,5}]`. The difficulty is determining the integral of `F[] Conjugate[F[]]` over all `k` and `kp`.

Comment: @Sid Look at fig.2. On line `k+kp=0`, we have `Abs[F[]]=const`, hence the integral you are looking for is divergent.